# tar over ssh to IPv6 host

Tags: linux, ipv6, tar

I want to tar to a remote host using the remote host's IPv6 address. I can ssh and scp to the host but GNU tar does not accept the IPv6 address.

I tried:

```
tar -cjvf root@2001:DB8::1234:5678:/backup.tar.bz2 *
```

and

```
tar -cjvf root@[2001:DB8::1234:5678]:/backup.tar.bz2 *
```

and

```
tar -cjvf root@\[2001:DB8::1234:5678\]:/backup.tar.bz2 *
```

but none of these work. All of these give address errors from tar. My Ubuntu system has tar version 1.25-3.

Comment: This is likely a depreciated feature in GNU tar, and is not caused by IPv6 at all. Can you please provide a screenshot which shows that root@host:/path will work for IPv4 hosts? Also, instead of just showing us the command which you used, please show the command *and* the errors and output.

Comment: Also, you might be looking for `--rsh-command=/path/to/ssh`, which is vaguely hinted at http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar .

Comment: I haven't see anything in the GNU docs that describes this feature as depreciated and it does work for IPv4 (you can easily try both IPv4 and IPv6).Yes, I should have included the error output which has tar complaining about that it couldn't write that device. The --rsh-command is not needed since GNU tar on CentOS/Ubuntu is compiled  to automatically use ssh instead of rsh and this wouldn't affect the destination IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer (actually already had the answer before asking but figured this would help others and I did learn something). Breaking the tar and ssh into two different steps worked.

```
tar cvjf - * | ssh root@2001:DB8::1234:5678 "dd of=/backup/backup.tar.bz2"
```

**Note: I tried using cat instead of dd but cat did not work for me - tar gave write errors.** May be if I was using ssh key authentication instead of password it would have worked.

Reference:

http://www.astrouw.edu.pl/~jskowron/tar-ssh/

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-tar-command-through-network-over-ssh-session/

Answer (score 9):

Since it works over SSH, you can use:

```
tar cjvf - /folder/to/backup | ssh root@ipv6 "cat > data.tar.bz2"
```

Comment: Remember to add `-e none` to `ssh`, otherwise some bytes may get corrupted.

Comment: The tar pipe won't allocate a `pty`, so `-e` option doesn't apply (I tested using the default `~` and `-e a` and it wouldn't treat either as an escape character).

Comment: You're right, I didn't know that, thank you.

Comment: I tried running cat in the ssh remote command but I got write errors. I was able to get the command working by using dd instead of cat.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're imputing powers to tar that it doesn't actually have.  No version of `tar` to which I have immediate access suggests that the `-f` flag takes an argument which is a remote user/machine pair.

Could you say why you think this will work?

Comment: It does work for GNU tar but not AT&T or older BSD tar - it makes use of the BSD rsh (but uses ssh) and rmt system. See the bottom of this page: http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/file.html#SEC104

Comment: But as the bottom of that page says, "The remote host is accessed using the rsh program, with a username of user".  I'm delighted to learn about the ability to auto-access a remote machine (thank you!), but I don't know anyone who's permitted rsh in a donkey's age.  It certainly mentions nothing about being willing to use ssh as a transport mechanism.